# Doorkeeper jwt with RS encryption

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, doorkeeper

I am using Doorkeeper for authorization and JWT to generate access token in my application. And enabled below option like

- **secret_key_path** location to my private.pem file
- **encryption_method** is RS256
- **use_application_secret** false

using Doodkeeper::JWT configure block. Issue I am facing is once request hit for token generation in backend it prompts for Enter PEM pass phrase:

and not getting any response back because its waiting Pass phrase to enter once you provided phrase then you will get access token as response.

Note : I generate private.pem file for encryptions and using in JWT to generate access_token using private.pem.

Comment: either you can remove `passphrase` to you're file or You can use `secret_key` and load it from `ENV`.

Comment: @UdAY I added secret_key but still it prompts and how we can remove passpharse ?

Comment: after adding secret key comment the `secret_key_path` and you can check [here](https://knowledge.digicert.com/solution/SO5292.html) regarding removing passphrase

Comment: I resolved by adding monkey patch like below:
#   secret_key_file_open {|f| OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(f)}
module JWT
    class << self
      def rsa_key_file
        secret_key_file_open {|f| OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(f, Doorkeeper::JWT.configuration.secret_key)}
      end
    end
  end
end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue the secret is not passed to OpenSSL so I modified as below by 
reopened the JWT module and added to monkey patch

```
module JWT
class << self
  def rsa_key_file
    secret_key_file_open {|f| OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(f, Doorkeeper::JWT.configuration.secret_key)}
  end
end
end
```